# If statement evaluates as boolean regardless of content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Not sure if I'm going crazy but I'm getting a weird error in my view, the error shown in VS for the `Array.IndexOf(...)` is: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`

- If I move my cursor to the end of `Array.IndexOf(...)` it says `)
  expected`
- If I remove the if statement, no errors.
- If I put anything into the `if()` it gives me the same error.
- The foreach is within another foreach loop

  ```
  <!-- HTML -->
  @foreach (HROC.Models.OUNode node in OUNode.Children)
      {
      string textBranchId = @node.Position.ToString();

      if (Array.IndexOf(collapseSArray, "unit_" + textBranchId) <  0)
      {
          collapseClass = "collapse";
      }
      else
      {
          collapseClass = "in";
      }
  <!-- HTML -->
  ...
  }
  ```

Comment: What is the definition of collapseSArray array?

Comment: Is collapseSArray an array of strings?

Comment: @RyanB @TGH yes, if I separate `Array.IndexOf(collapseSArray, "unit_" + textBranchId)` it evaluates correctly (to an int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in doubt, split things out. Also remove redundant `@` symbols.

```
@foreach (HROC.Models.OUNode node in OUNode.Children)
{
    //Removed @ before node...
    string textBranchId = node.Position.ToString();

    //Split out this line
    var indexPos = Array.IndexOf(collapseSArray, "unit_" + textBranchId);

    if (indexPos < 0)
    {
        collapseClass = "collapse";
    }
    else
    {
        collapseClass = "in";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the redundant @ symbol was the culprit